# Проблема - Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, база-данных

Пробую вывести данные из бд, а в итоге получаю ошибку.
Вот Код

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$ID = $_REQUEST[ID];
$ID = "1";
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Client` WHERE ID = " . "$ID") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        $client[ID] = $row[ID];
        $client[Surname] = $row[Surname];
        $client[Name] = $row[Name];
        $client[Middlename] = $row[Middlename];
    }
}

echo(json_decode($client));
?>
```

Ругается на эту строчку

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
```

Объясните как это решить, желательно конкретно сказать, почему он ругается на количество, которое я ему передаю.

Answer (score -1):

Я дурак и написал

```
echo(json_decode($client));
```

а нужно было

```
echo(json_encode($client));
```

Comment: эта строчка не имеет к эой ошибке ни малейшего отношения